# How do I detach a trailer from a tractor?

Tags: mods, grand-theft-auto-san-andreas

Attaching trailers to a tractor or a tug is fairly easy: just back into the tow pin with your tractor, and it'll latch. The only way to un-latch it is to make a maneuver that forces the connection to be severed, there is no other way of detaching trailers.

OK, got that.

Now, I was pretty sure that with help like [CLEO](http://cleo.li/), someone must've made a mod like that. I've searched the web far and wide, but (aside from that fact, that searching for anything with the word "trailer" brings up movie trailers) I found many interesting and vastly more complicated things, than simply a function to detach the trailer of a semi.

Now, there's things like [mods that let you detach and reattach train cars](http://www.gamemodding.net/en/gta-san-andreas/gta-sa-cleo-scripts/51347-otcepka-vagonov.html). I was under the impression that the trailers of semis should work similarly.

I also found an old [forum post](http://gtaforums.com/topic/368783-relcleo-detach-trailer/) advertising something very similar to what I'd need, but unfortunately, all the links mentioned there are dead.

I also found a mod, [that reaches deep into the game data and changes quite a bit of it](http://www.gtagarage.com/mods/show.php?id=392). It also does *way* more that I'd ask for.

The reason why I can't use it is because it seems to break the game. No idea if it's due to a newer CLEO version, maybe it doesn't like the Steam version of the game. In any event, the game crashes while starting when this plugin is installed (I manually made a backup of the files this is overwriting, beforehand).

At this point, I believe I'm simply looking in the wrong direction. Even though this function hasn't been included in the original game, given that people have been releasing far more complex CLEO mods and scripts for GTA:SA since the game has been released - and are still releasing it, thanks to SA-MP, a comparatively simple function add-on seems almost trivial.

At this point, I'm asking for suggestions on what mod or plugin to use, or if I'm doing something conceptually wrong to begin with.

Comment: Steam version of GTA:SA is not that good with mods.

Comment: @ardaozkal I know, but in the case of CLEO, it plays nice. That mod I was referring to, is not using CLEO at all, it kinda overwrites parts of the game files, and such. There is also no other way of uninstalling that mod, other than re-installing GTA:SA or using manual backup, like I did.

Comment: Sorry for this, but just reread the question and you are asking for a mod/plugin... that is unfortunately off topic.

Comment: @ardaozkal - Unless something's changed that I'm not aware of, Mod rec is not treated the same as Game Rec, and as off the current consensus: *"On our site, these questions take a form where a mod is generally a solution to a problem. Judge questions by the problem being posed instead of the presupposed answer."* - from [Is “mod rec” really an umbrella category that we want to use? Or is it confusing the situation?](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/a/6830/28182), referenced in the ['Community Consensus' Post](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/a/7867/28182)

Comment: @Robotnik It seems the asker is well aware of the limitations of the game, and is searching for a mod that expands specific functionality.  I think it falls rather handily into mod-rec.

Comment: @Frank - OP does state *"[looking for mod suggestions] or if I'm doing something conceptually wrong to begin with"* meaning he is open to non-mod-rec answers, which I believe my answer shows

Comment: @Robotnik, ah, sorry for it, but allowing mod rec and banning all others is kinda weird tbh. I retracted my close vote.

Answer (score 1):

GTA San Andreas is the first game after GTA 2 to reintroduce the ability to pull loads. The game mechanics of attaching to and pulling a trailer is roughly the same as in GTA 2, but trailers may decouple from a vehicle using a specific command or if physical force (i.e. jackknifing, dislodging due to rough terrains or jumps, excessive speed, etc.) is subjected to the trailer.

> However, there is no single button to detach the trailers.

There is a glitch in the PS2 version where taking a picture of the attachment will detach the trailers but the glitch is fixed in subsequent versions.

Along with the game's three semi-trailer trucks (the Linerunner, Tanker and Roadtrain), the game also introduces a different range of vehicles with roughly the same capability, including:

The Tow Truck, which employs an adjustable boom at the back to pull any large vehicle.
The Tractor, which uses an adjustable tow hitch to pull smaller hauls or large vehicles.
The Utility Van and Baggage, which feature a stationary tow hitch to pull smaller hauls.
The trailers themselves consist of a more varied range of items, some of which are not available unless they are spawned using a third-party trainer. In total, GTA San Andreas features eight types of trailers: Four semi-trailers and four specialized trailers.

All trailers in general are capable of exploding entirely if severely damaged or flipped over, but specialized trailers have several other peculiarities, including functional headlights and taillights that light up at night or in a dark location, and the ability to emit smoke if sufficiently damaged (Including those that would never burn, much less explode). This is because all trailers are classified as vehicles, although they are defined with a different classification to other road vehicles.

Truck trailers are prominently used in the Trucking side missions.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I have a hard enough time **keeping** the trailer attached to the cab. Every slight dip or bump seems to detach it!

There are some types of vehicles such as Tow Trucks and Farm tractors which can manually attach & detach to vehicles by adjusting the angle of the tow piece. This can be accomplished with moving <kbd>R3</kbd> (PS2, PS3), Right stick on other console versions, or the numpad keys on PC. Unfortunately this feature does not exist 'As is' on the Semi Trailer cab.

I am unaware of any mods that add a manual detach option, however the 'official' way to release a Semi Trailer from the Truck/Cab is to jacknife the truck by reversing back while turning until the trailer is making around a 90 degree angle with the cab, at which point it will pop off.

It's not the most intuitive of controls but it is the most reliable way of detaching & positioning a trailer, and probably your best bet to stick to.

Comment: I heard of some solution on PS2/PS3, where it was possible to take a photo of the connector. That would disengage the connections, etc. It doesn't work on PC, it seems. Problem is, when making a roadtrain kindof arrangement (works best with baggage tug and several of the baggage carts, and a airplane stairs at the end) getting them in one go is kinda difficult. Attaching and reattaching the trailers would be just sensical. Also, they managed to implement quite complicated thrust vectoring for the Hydra, so not having that function seems almost like an oversight.

Comment: @polemon - it probably is an oversight or at the very least they thought people wouldn't worry too much about detaching a track cab from a trailer given most missions involving semi trailers require the trailer to be attached.